# Why is typescript compiling away local variables of my base controller using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to create a base controller to access form information using Typescript/Angular, my problem is that the `form` member seems to be compiled away aka, it does not exist in the resulting JavaScript.

Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
export class FormController {

    form: ng.IFormController;

    constructor() {
    }

    showValidation(fieldName: string, errorType: string): boolean {
        var field = this.form[fieldName];
        var fieldError = typeof errorType === 'undefined' ? field.$invalid : field.$error[errorType];
        return !field.$pristine && fieldError;
    }

}}

export class ImplController extends FormController {

    constructor(private $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
        super();
    }


    public validateField(): boolean {
        return this.showValidation('field-name', 'invalid');
    }

}
```

The resulting JS looks something like:

```
var FormController = (function () {
    function FormController() {
    }
    FormController.prototype.showValidation = function (fieldName, errorType) {
              ...
    };
    return FormController;
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties declared outside of the constructor are a TypeScript construct only, and do not exist in JavaScript's language specification - they're purely designed to give TypeScript a better understanding on your class' properties.

To further demonstrate this, if you were to take the following TypeScript:

```
class TestClass {
    myString: string = "Hello";
    constructor(){}
}
```

and run it through the TypeScript compiler, targeting ES6 instead of 5, it'll look like this:

```
class Tester {
    constructor() {
        this.myString = "Hello";
    }
}
```

**However**, if you weren't to assign a value to your variable, the TypeScript compiler will strip it out:

```
class TestClass {
    myString: string;
    constructor(){}
}
```

transpiles to this:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(){}
}
```

**Update**

Further to your comment, the reason you're getting an error is you're not assigning a value to your property - so the TypeScript compiler will strip it out. If you were to assign it a value of something structurally equivilent `IFormController` then it would not error.

Comment: i get an error accessing the form though, saying undefined, perhaps the problem then is the ng-formcontroller not getting injected in?

Comment: What does the body of your `showValidation` function look like?

Comment: dont have it open right now, but pretty much as above (slightly modified), but as it hits, `this.form` I get a Cannot read property of undefined

Comment: Does, ng.IFormController have to reside on Scope?

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference as IFormController is just an interface. I'm not sure what would assign a value to form. As it stands it's just a property that hasn't been set.